# Swift Alamofire can not parse the response JSON string in POST request

Tags: swift, alamofire

A POST http request:

```
 task.request = sessionManager?.request(url!, method: method, parameters: paramters, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
      task.handleResponse(response: response)
 }
```

The response is a JSON string like this:

```
{\"Data\":{\"ArrayOfItems\":[{\"ActualQty\":\"5.0\",\"BatchManaged\":true,\"ArrayOfBatches\":[{\"BatchNumber\":1,\"Counted\":\"ADD\", \"Quantity\":10},{\"BatchNumber\":2,\"Counted\":\"ADD\", \"Quantity\":10}],\"LineNum\":\"1\",\"ItemCode\":\"M1001-L\",\"WarehouseCode\":\"Store\"}],\"Comments\":\"Ht\",\"DocEntry\":\"1\",\"Quantiry\":\"123\",\"Initials\":\"RT\"},\"PromptAnswerValue\":[]}
```

The Alamofire can not parse the response JSON string. Errors is flonwing:

```
responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around character 40." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 40.}))
```

Debuged, the failed in 'let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: validData, options: options)' line. See attached file flowing:

[image]

The validData is valuable. Why is this happening?

I write a demo and I can receving the response json string, the code like this:

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("\(jsonData.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = jsonData as Data
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {(
        data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        let dataString =  String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let dict = self.getDictionaryFromJSONString(jsonString: dataString!)
        print(dict)
    }
    task.resume()
```

Used the URLSession can do this, but why the Alamofire can not? Is it the problem I use? Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issues I had solved. This is caused by the invalid JSON string in response.

1. Debug as flowing:

Debug here and do this in the console

```
po String(data: validData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

2. Check if the JSON string is valid.

Besides, note: Use JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted.